# How can I make an outline for a mesh but only on the exterior part?

Tags: mesh, shaders, camera, shader-nodes

I've been struggling with making an outline that does only show on the exterior part of the mesh, not like the solidify outline that also works with parts of the interior.
What I am looking for is something like the Golden Sun Dark Dawn overworld character outline, or the orange line in the viewport for that matter.

I think it probably has to do with the camera, but any advice will be helpful, so thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Search for freestyle here or yt or google

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To get an outline   ***only around*** the object you can use the compositor with this node set-up[image]
The blur control the thickness of the outline.
It has the drawback to turn sharp angles contour into smooth contour. If you want sharp contour, use the freestyle option and choose ***contour*** for your ***edge type*** under ***Freestyle Line Set***

[image]

Here is some documentation related to your question:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_set.html

https://3dtotal.com/tutorials/t/blender-freestyle-render-engine-filippo-veniero-blender-rendering-fillipo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emz5metjCk4&ab_channel=PaulOCaggegi

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7mr71nfjFY&ab_channel=BlenderMadeEasy