# How can i emphasize my "shading edges"?

Tags: shader-nodes

So i have these shader nodes here:

[image]

which are giving me this nice result because of the bump:

[image]

now i would like this "edges" in another color.

Please be aware that i am using voronoi "n-sphere-radius"! The easy solution with mix color node didn't work for me.

How is this possible?

i tried this...but it didn't work:

[image]

Comment: what does it give if you plug your Voronoi into a ColorRamp with your white and red that you plug into the Base Color of the Principled BSDF?

Comment: [perhaps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/265611/111042)?

Comment: @moonboots: this works with "normal voronoi" but unfortunately doesn't work with n-sphere radius

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compare the results of *N-Sphere-Radius* and *Distance-To-Edge* Functions of the Voronoi Texture, you will see that both produce essentially the same "texture shape".

The only difference is that the *N-Sphere Radius* will give you these differently toned "Face Indices"
[image]

While the *Distance To Edge* will provide, well, the distance from the center of one cell to its edge in a grayscale gradient:

[image]

So, unless you really want to go the hard way and use the N-Sphere no-matter-the-cost, i would suggest you take the 'Distance' option. Here is a quick Setup that might give you a good start:

[image]

Note: Both Color Ramp stops are very much crunched to the left end to get these sharp blue lines.

EDIT: If this approach creates too many blue lines, as Gordon Brinkmann stated in the comments, you can subtract (clamped) the Distance from the N-Sphere. Adjust the result with color ramps:
[image]

Comment: I was just working on the same answer, the only problem I had which might be not what @Chris wants, is that with _N-Sphere Radius_ neighbouring faces can have the same color which then does not result in a visible edge if you plug it into the bump - but the _Distance to Edge_ function will show an edge there. That's why I hesitated to give an answer.

Comment: You are right again! :-) I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to figure out a solution but didn't find one yet. The subtraction doesn't work either because as you can see in your example, in the upper part of the left face there are some edges missing where they should be some. If Chris wants to have the blue edges exactly where the bump has edges it's still not correct. I guess he will have to compromise.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same texture connected to another Ramp, use a mix node and plug it into.

Correction - Use the "DISTANCE" as the "Mix" factor. And color to the ramp.

[image]

Comment: try your proposal with n-sphere radius as i did - and you will see - it won't work